# error C2065: 'resultImgs' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, declaration, identifier

I'm getting an error 'error C2065: 'resultImgs' : undeclared identifier' when compiling this. What is wrong here? Please help!

```
    {
        // record all non-zero responses in case we need to do further research
        // but in fact, we only need the max response as the final result
        responses.push_back(response);
        IplImage* resultImg = siftController.setResultImg(it->ptr.get(),image);
        resultImgs.push_back(BasicCvApi::MyImagePtr(resultImg));
        strings.push_back(it->className);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tell me it's just a typo of `resultImg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mesage is clear enough: the compiler does not see definition of name  `resultImgs`. So check this name taking into account the spelling of the name